# Subclass of subclass of PFObject not being registered

Tags: ios, parse-platform, subclass, pfobject

I have a class called `Attendee` which inherits from `PFObject`. I also have another class called `Speaker` which is a child of `Attendee`.

Below are the class definition for `Attendee` & `Speaker`

```
class Attendee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Attendee"
    }
}

class Speaker: Attendee {
    override class func initialize() {
        var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
}
```

I register both in my `applicationDidFinishLaunch` method before using any parse features:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Speaker.initialize()
    Attendee.initialize()

    Parse.setApplicationId(ObjectManager.appID, clientKey: ObjectManager.clientKey)

    ...
}
```

However, when I try to use the `Attendee` and `Speaker` classes later on in my code, I get this error:

`The class MedConf.Attendee must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse.`

The code that triggers the error is: 
`var attendee = Attendee()`

I don't understand why this is happening, as I clearly register both the subclasses before I do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is you can't subclass any class the implements a PFSubclassing protocol. Try making the Speaker it's own class and build the relationship use the relationship API in Parse. If you need a resource to build relational data, check here. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-relational-data